# Export K2 content from a joomla web site and Import to another website

Tags: migration, k2

I've a large amount of Joomla's K2 Categories and Items in website A.

Now I need to have whole K2 Categories and Items of Website A in Website B.
Are the any ways to export K2 data and import them into another website?

One more problem is that website A uses Joomla 2.5.x and Website B is using Joomla 3.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We actually bought a commercial plugin to do this. So far it seems to work well, without you having to mess with real database exports and getting into mysql.

[K2 Import Component](http://www.individual-it.net/en/Instructions-for-K2-Import-Component.html)

Comment: I'll try this later, I do not like to play with database, because I'm not so expert in mySql.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way by exporting required k2 tables in your hosting phpmyadmin in Site A and then import those tables in Site B database.in site B you have to have k2 installed, after export, to check if there are any k2 table column missing, you have to go extension manager->database page and need to click fix.

For this kind of exporting, you have to export site A's user related tables in site B else k2 item, comments, users, usergroups tables' user related data will be incorrect. But if you don't care about these user related data then you have to manually modify fields data(like 'created by' in items table) in site A's exported sql file before importing to site B.

I actually moved large k2 contents to one of my destination site by export and import successfully.I don't know if there are any worked out k2 extension available to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have any experience in mySql databases, but it seems that I should start digging mySql.

Answer (score 1):

You will need phpMyAdmin for this, this will by kind a surgery. This is joomla 2.5 to 2.5.

I am migrating from site A to site B, same template and everything but i had a problem, i imported a Database that was out of date and now i need only import some k2 items and i want to avoid to redo everything again, so by analysis the K2 tables in my DB i found the next tables are involved: (the ces_ is my table prefix it may vary from yours).

In my case the categories and users are the same so i don't care about them, but you can extract them from k2_categories and k2_users accordingly.

```
ces_k2_attachments
ces_k2_categories
ces_k2_comments
ces_k2_extra_fields
ces_k2_extra_fields_groups
ces_k2_items
ces_k2_rating
ces_k2_tags
ces_k2_tags_xref
ces_k2_users
ces_k2_user_groups
```

In PhpMyAdmin go to search tab and set your criteria, in my case 42 is the super user that created the items i want to move (i found this at the k2_users table):

```
SELECT * FROM `ces_k2_items` WHERE `created_by` = 42
```

How to export query results on PhpMyAdmin:
https://serverfault.com/questions/300316/how-export-result-of-mysql-query-on-phpmyadmin-3-4-3

make sure you copy the images stored at:

```
/media/k2/items/cache
```

The just simply import the rows you already exported using your SQL criteria to your DB using the import tools of phpmyadmin.

This procedure worked for me i hope it helps you.